# HashMap returning null

Tags: java

I'm working on creating a command line game in Java. The basic premise that there is a Game class and Room class: get to the correct room and the game ends.

From each room the user can move a direction:

```
public void move (String direction) {
     Room nextRoom = currentLocation.getNeighbor(direction); //this is the problem, always nil
     if (nextRoom == null){
         msg = "You can't go in that direction";
        }else{
         currentLocation = nextRoom;
         msg = currentLocation.getLongDescription();
     }
  }
```

The problem is, this .getNeighbor method is returning nil, so the issue is with my getNeighbor method within my Room class or maybe with how I'm creating the rooms. Here is my getNeighbor method within the Room Class:

```
public Room getNeighbor(String rDirection){
        Room next = map.get(rDirection);
        return next;
    }
```

This takes my string, and looks at a HashMap map I've created to see if their is a room in that direction key. I'm afraid the issue is how I'm creating my room's direction HashMap:

In my Room Class:

```
private HashMap<String , Room> map = new HashMap<String , Room>();
```

I have a create map method in my room class that I call when initializing my game. Here's the method for adding the directions and then what I'm calling in my Game Class:

```
// Room Class Method

    public void addNeighbor(String rDirection, Room r){
        map.put(rDirection, r);
    }

// Game Class - Initializing the Rooms

kitchen.addNeighbor("east", foyer);
kitchen.addNeighbor("north", library);
```

I am unable to find a neighbor to my room from any room I look. The errors occur on the commented line but I think it's really with my Room Class methods, or the way I'm creating the HashMap(I've never used one before). Anyway, I was wondering if someone could help point out what I seem to be missing, and why no matter what my room's do not have any neighbors in my map. Thanks a ton.

Comment: For better help sooner: 1) Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see nothing obviously wrong in the snippets.  I suggest that you run the code using a debugger an examine the states of the respective objects.

FWIW, a call to `HashMap<String,Room>.get(x)` will return `null` if (and only if) one of the following:

- there is no map entry for `x`, or
- the map entry for `x` is `null`.

---

If I was to make a guess, it would be that you haven't properly initialized the `Room` instance that `currentLocation` refers to.  For instance, if `currentLocation` referred to the kitchen, then maybe you are trying to go `"south"` or maybe `foyer` was `null`.

Another possibility is that the `direction` String has the wrong spelling or capitalization, and is therefore not matching one of the directions that you configured.

(And on that note, you program will be more robust if you declared an `enum` to represent the recognized directions, and used that as the key type for the map ... and throughout the rest of your program.)

Comment: The issue was a matter of scope/order where I was starting the current location to a room before generating the values for said room. I truly appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is really more of a "comment" than an "answer", but it won't fit in a comment, so here goes . . .

There's nothing obviously wrong with the code that you've included in your question. The problem is probably elsewhere. One thing that will help you debug is if you change this:

```
 if (nextRoom == null){
     msg = "You can't go in that direction";
    }
```

to something like this:

```
if(nextRoom == null)
{
    System.out.println("Illegal direction '" + direction + "' requested from" +
                       " room '" + currentLocation.getDescription() + "'.");
    System.out.println("(map is: " + map + ")");
    msg = "You can't go in that direction";
}
```

That will tell you *exactly* what `direction` is, and *exactly* what `direction` can be. Some things to look out for:

- case-sensitivity, if `direction` is (say) `"East"` rather than `"east"`.
- whitespace, if `direction` is (say) `"east "` rather than `"east"`.
- map entries that are present, but with the value being `null`. (`kitchen.addNeighbor("east", foyer);` won't help anything if `foyer` is `null` when you do the insertion.)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly address your question (like others, I didn't see anything that jumps out other than case sensitivity and such), but I'd suggest using an enum as your key, rather than a String. Strings are good for describing text, but they tend to be imperfect substitute for other things (like direction).

An enum would have some advantages over String in this case:

- It makes the code self-documenting; you can easily see exactly which values methods might expect

  - For instance, you don't need to remember if it's called "NORTH", "north", "North" or "Up". It's just Direction.NORTH, and it won't compile if you don't get it right
  - This is useful for callers as well as implementers
- you can create your Map as an EnumMap instead of HashMap, which is more efficient (though this may not be an issue in your application)